# Невозможность возврата на предыдущую активити

Tags: java, android, activity

Доброго времени суток. У меня такой вопрос. Имеется android приложение в котором пользователь может авторизоваться. И есть кнопка выхода, по нажатии на которую пользователь разлогинивается и ему показывается форма авторизации. Но дело в том что если нажать на кнопку "назад" (ту которая относится к самой операционной системе, а не в приложении), то происходит возврат на предыдущую активити, на которую разлогиненный пользователь попадать не должен. 
Можно ли как-то убить предыдущую активити если была нажата кнопка выхода? Или вообще как то предотвратить попадание на нее если пользователь разлогинился?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете самостоятельно обрабатывать нажатие кнопки "назад" с помощью метода активити [`onBackPressed`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()).
В этом методе вы можете проверять состояние логина и, к примеру, в зависимости от результата, очищать стек переходов или перейти в нужное по ситуации место.

Так же вы можете в манифесте указать для активити , на которую попадать по кнопке назад никто не должен, атрибут `android:noHistory="true"` - это исключит попадание активити в стек возвратов вообще и в нее нельзя будет попасть по кнопке "назад" никаким способом - ни залогиненому не разлогининому пользователю.

Answer (score 0):

Перед запуском новой активити вызывайте метод `finish()`  у старой активити, это закроет вашу старую активити